# Stripe copy customer

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We have a use case in which, multiple merchants link their stripe account to our platform account and cards are stored in our platform account.

We are looking for a solution by which we can create a **direct charge** in merchants account by using the card saved in our platform account.

Is there a way to copy customer(with card) from platform account to connected merchant account so that we can create a charge in merchant account?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be achieved by creating a token against a customer(in you platform account) and using it to create a new customer in merchant account.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following manner using stripe request option.

```
StripeTokenCreateOptions token = new StripeTokenCreateOptions();
token.CustomerId = <customer_id_in_platform_account>;
StripeToken stripeToken = tokenService.Create(token, stripeRequestOptions);

//create customer on business
StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = CreateCustomer(stripeToken.Id, stripeRequestOptions);
```

In stripe request option you can set the connected account id in which you have to copy the customer.

you can further read about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers).